# How to query Import.io from a frontend JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, import.io

I would like to develop a simple javascript app that needs to have access to data provided by a Import.io connector. I do not want to expose my API Key so the recommended way for this scenario would be to [create a signed URL](http://api.docs.import.io/). I have tried to "encrypt" my query URL with the PHP script provided in the docs but I keep getting errors:

> {
>       "error": "Bad data formatting in signed URL",
>       "code": "BAD_PARAMETER" }

The URL in question: https://api.import.io/store/connector/a57db986-8cd1-4540-9234-e52c5ed2d8ae/_query?format=JSON&input=webpage/url:http://www.imdb.com/chart/top&_user=209c0d95-8f9a-4b6e-a96a-457aea9f0e41&_expiry=1434717924000&_digest=sM66ffzeV/MH7O+EW0z0UND18CQ=%

Perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way altogether. Could somebody walk me through the steps of how to do this?

Comment: Did you try encoding the URL parameters that you send to the API ?

Comment: Yeah, tried encoding pretty much everything in all possible combinations.